# htaccess RewriteRule - Multiple optional parameters in no particular order

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need friendly urls on my webpage and I'm using the htaccess file for that purpose.
Actually it's pretty easy, but there are some pages where the url can have multiple optional parameters in no particular order and I can't image how the rewrite rule shpuld look like for those pages.

For example, a page to display a huge list of movies from the database. You can filter by medium (dvd, blu-ray), age, genre. You can sort the results by alphabet, rating, etc. and you can switch pages. All of this works with url paremeters.

```
index.php?movies
```

Shows all movies, no filters, no sorting. The rewritten url should lie this:

```
/movie
```

No problem so far. But it can also look like this:

```
index.php?movies&medium=1&genre=3&age=17&sort=alphabet&page=15
```

This would return page 15 of all R-rated horror movies on dvd, ordered by name.

The parameters have no particular order and are all optional. If my RewriteRule would loo like this

```
RewriteRule ^movies/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$
```

how do you know if the first parameter is medium or page or whatever?
Is there a way to identify the parameters?

```
/movies/genre-3/page-15
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use urls like this: `/movies/medium?1/genre/3&age/17/sort/alphabet/page=15` to support multiple parameters in URI.

Comment: But what does the rewrite rule look like?

Comment: ok posted my answer below, see if this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# reucrsion based rule to convert /n1/v1/n2/v2 to /?n2=v2&n1=v1
RewriteRule "([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$" $3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This rewrites a URI like `/movies/medium/1/genre/3&age/17/sort/alphabet/page/15` to:
`/?page=15&sort=alphabet&3&age=17&1=genre&movies=medium`